# Cocoa block variables memory management

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

```
void f(NSString *s)
{
    [someObj doSomethingWithCompletionHandler:^()
    {
        doSomethingElse(s);
    }];
}

void g()
{
    NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] initWith....];
    f(s);
    [s release];
}
```

Is there a problem in this code? I guess `s` might be destroyed before `completionHandler` is called and a garbage would be passed into `doSomethingElse`. Am I right? If yes, how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's okay, the block retains `s`. So `s` doesn't get released when you call `[s release]`.

Further information: you can run into problems if you create a retain cycle. Most often it looks like this:

```
[self doSomeThingWithCompletionHandler:^()
{
   [self beHappy];
}
```

The self does retain the block, the block retains self, voila. But it doesn't have to be so obvious:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = @{@"someKey" : someObj, @"someOtherKey", someOtherObj};
//
// lots of stuff happening here
//
[someObj doSomethingWithCompletionHandler:^()
{
   id someOtherObj = dictionary[@"someOtherKey"]
}]
```

The solution is to declare a weak variable:

```
__weak id weakSelf = self;
[self doSomethingWithCompletionHandler:^()
{
    //and to make sure it stays valid if you do multithreaded stuff
    __strong id strongSelf = weakSelf;
   [strongSelf beHappy];
}];
```

edit: as pointed out in the comments, the original post was using non-ARC code. In this case you have to replace `__weak` with `__unsafe_unretained`

Comment: __weak is only available with ARC, but OP uses manual reference counting.